# Bot Framework Composer - Adaptive card - Submit and Cancel Buttons

Tags: chatbot, adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

I have 2 buttons on the adaptive card, "Submit" and "Cancel"."Submit" brings me the information I entered on the form. but the "Cancel" button does the same. I want the "Cancel" button to redirect to another dialog when pressed. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data property for this and then add a condition getting the value of **turn.activity.value.id**

```
        "actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Submit",
        "data": {
            "id": "submit"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Cancel",
        "data": {
            "id": "cancel"
        }
    }
    ]
```